# django - understanding LocaleMiddleWare (translation.deactivate)

Tags: django, internationalization

I use django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware to get a website i18n'ed and to make a language 'switcher' via [set_language redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view).

And I just can not understand a couple of things:

1. why does it call `translation.deactivate` ([source on github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/locale.py#L42)) during process_responce?
2. Does it mean that I can not using this middleware? (It just shows a page in a different language once, and then switches back.)

Answer (score 2):

`translation.deactivate` is called because the current language is stored in a global (thread local) variable. It is set when a request comes in, and must be un-set when that request is finished to prevent it "leaking" into the next request (ex, imagine a thread handles a request which must be localized to Portuguese, then another request where no localization is set. If Portuguese localization wasn't deactivated, the next request would also be localized to Portuguese).